# jQuery UI Accordion with custom scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am playing around with jQuery UI Accordion and i am trying to use jQuery UI Slider as a custom scrollbar (don't ask me why, i am just messing around). I have set the max-height of each accordion to 500px.

I then want to loop over every accordion and check if the height is over 500px. If it is i will put in the slider as a scrollbar. However on load the accordions are closed and their height returns as 0.

```
$('#scroller').height();
```

Does anyone know how to get the height on load??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put `$('#scroller').height();` inside the function that expands the accordian? That way you always get the up-to-date info.